# Custom MakeBoxes are issued also for different pattern expressions

Tags: boxes

Suppose I want to display some expression, say `foo[p1_,p2_]`, as a point in a circle.

I can achieve this using `MakeBoxes`, like in the following:

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo /: MakeBoxes[foo[p1_, p2_], fmt_] := 
 GraphicsBox[{CircleBox[{0, 0}], PointSize@0.08, PointBox[{p1, p2}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 70]
```

which produces the desired result:

[image]

However, a problem arises when I use `??foo`:

[image]

As you can see, Mathematica is also issuing `MakeBoxes` on the `foo[p1_,p2_]` that should appear in the informations.
Infact, the problem can be traced back to the fact that also the expression

```
foo[a_,b_]
```

triggers the `MakeBoxes` evaluation.

How can this problem be avoided?

PS: apologies for the not-much-informative title, please change it if you find a better way to describe the question.

Comment: Why not restrict the argument, since the display will only make sense for those arguments: `MakeBoxes[foo[p1_?NumberQ, p2_?NumberQ], fmt_]`?

Answer (score 2):

I concur with the answer J.M. gave in a comment to the question, but would limit evaluation by a condition that constrain the coordinates given to lie on or within the unit circle.

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo /: MakeBoxes[foo[p1_, p2_] /; Norm[{p1, p2}] <= 1, form_] := 
  GraphicsBox[{CircleBox[{0, 0}], PointSize @ .08, PointBox[{p1, p2}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 70]
```

Testing with points along the ray through `{1, 1}`

```
foo[#, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, .5]
```

[image: test1]

Testing with points lying on the circle.

```
foo @@@ N[CirclePoints[5]]
```

[image: test2]

??foo

[image: info]